# AIR OpenWithDefaultApplication

Tags: apache-flex, air

I try to open a doc file whose is stored on remote server (on my web server).
To do that, I try to use Openwithdefaultapplication, but it's seems that remote path is not allowed. Could you help me to find a solution to do that.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the file to the local computer first. If you use File.download(), then AIR will put up a dialog for the user to choose a save location. If that's not desired, you can download using the URLLoader class (and then open the downloaded file with openWithDefaultApplication).